# ViewScoped managed bean recreated on every request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope

I've managed to get a plain ViewScoped page going. I don't know if I don't understand something or this page isn't working as it should.
Every request it creates a new `Test` object even though it is ViewScoped and I can never get back the `theString` variable that I set.

Plain template with a input field, a button to set the value and a button to refresh the value displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton process="theInput" value="Set value" />
                <p:inputText id="theInput" value="#{test.theString}" /> --
            </h:form>

            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton process="theArea" update="theArea" value="Display value" />
            </h:form>

            <h:panelGroup id="theArea">
                #{test.theString}
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "test")
@ViewScoped
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private String theString = "initial";

    public String getTheString() {
        return theString;
    }

    public void setTheString(String theString) {
        this.theString = theString;
    }
}
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.7, Primefaces 5.2 and Glassfish 4.1

Shouldn't the `Test` object hold its state? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, what package did you import `@ViewScoped` from? There are two, one for JSF managed beans and other for CDI managed beans. The Javadoc tells which one is for which one.

Comment: I've imported it from `import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;`. I just saw that it also is possible to import `import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;`. Will try that one.